# Using Multiple Checkboxes in a Checkboxlist to filter results in a datalist

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-sql, datalist, checkboxlist

I am looking to provide a search for clients in which they can select multiple categores
(check boxes) and view only the results in those categories in a
gridView control. For instance example would
be if the user checks item price > 100 and price < 100 then they would only get items with respect to that checkbox selected and all the other selection criteria should not be populated to datalist.
I just dont know how to generate the dynamic multiple query depending on the selection and how will i get the selected checkbox list so that i can pass that to the sql query. Any help or tutorials will be appreciated. Also when the checkbox is deselected the items of that selection should dissapear from the datalist.

Issue Resolved:

```
 static public DataTable GetSelectedFilter(ArrayList test)
{

    string sqldef = "Select * from productDetail Where";
    string sql = "";
    int check = 0;
    int number  = test.Count;
   string OR = "OR";
    //ArrayList arrlist = new ArrayList();
    if (test.Count > 0)
    {

        while (number > check)
        {

                sql += "((Price between " + test[number - 1] + "))" + OR;


            number--;


        }

        string completeQuery = sqldef + sql;
        string sqltest = completeQuery.Substring(0, completeQuery.Length - 2);
        string finalQuery = sqltest + "order by Price";

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(finalQuery, ConnectionString);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
    else
    {
        string sql1 = "Select * from productDetail";

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql1, ConnectionString);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you doing your queries at the moment? ADO.NET, Linq To SQL, Entity Framework, etc?

Comment: Ado.net: string sql = "Select * from productDetail Where Price>2000 order by Price";
         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, ConnectionString);
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         da.Fill(dt);
         return dt;

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide assistance to cut and paste programmers.

Comment: i have cut nd paste from my code not from ny odar sources

Comment: I'm not saying that the code didn't come from your code base, but you seem not to understand basic programming (string concatenation for example) and that leads me to the belief that the code is largely copied from somewhere else otherwise you wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: Overall im just a beginer in this programming world, i was not expecting such an ego reply from an experienced programmer, After trying different stuff , i have asked d above question I tried different queries  to acheive that for instance: SELECT c.make, c.Price, c.makeID FROM dbo.productDetail c
WHERE ((@make NULL) OR (c.make = @make))
        AND ((@price IS NULL) OR (c.Price = @price))
        AND ((@makeID IS NULL) OR (c.makeID = @makeID))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with sql query , it works fine now